# How fix my git branches after squashing is master behind dev

Tags: git, git-squash

I have created 2 commits to remote `dev` branch. That I squashed and merge into remote `master` branch.

Now when I want to continue with working on `dev` branch - I don't know how can I correctly "repair" my branches - because after creating new pull request from `dev` to `master` I get list of all commits which were squashed in previous pull request.

I have something like this:

```
O ---- A ---- B ---- XY <--(master)
 \
  X ---- Y ---- Z <--(development)
```

How can I create correct pull request with commit Z from `dev` to `master`?

Comment: You should use the git bash or github ?

Comment: I am working with github

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Before adding new commits to your dev branch, you should first reset it to `origin/master`, since you `squashed/merge` dev to it.

In order to not break anything, create a new branch from origin/master:

```
cd /local/repo
git fetch
git checkout -b newBranch origin/master
```

Then report back your new commits on that new branch:

```
git cherry-pick Y..Z
```

Finally, reset your dev branch to said new branch:

```
git checkout dev
git reset --hard newBranch
```

And force push: `git push --force`.

The end result would be a new PR with only the new commits

Answer (score 1):

If you're unable to correctly determine the `Y` commit, in case we're talking about a much more complex scenario, reverting the `XY` commit from `master` also works:

```
git checkout master
git revert XY
git push
```

Then your pull request from `dev` to `master` will have no conflicts anymore.